# Android - Download multiple files or a zip with all of them

Tags: android, image, download, connection, zip

I need download around 300 images to my app but I didn't find anything saying which method is the most performance/connection friendly. Should I download and unzip the file on the device or download the images one by one?

Answer (score 3):

On a mobile device, making less connections is preferable, as it can be expensive to negotiate a network connection in the first place. A zip should be smaller than the individual files and it will definitely require far less data than downloading the individual files, due to less overhead as you now have one instead of 300 calls.

You should also be able to download the zip file faster than downloading the individual files, as there's less hand-shaking required to create and close connections.

Rule of thumb for me on mobiles is to do as much as possible in a call, so that you do not create and open multiple connections.  I've found it more efficient to add an additional 1k or 2k payload to a call than to make multiple calls to retrieve information.

Comment: There is a downside, the download and extract at least requires double space. If space enough, after the extraction you can delete the zip file.

Comment: @kelalaka - That is indeed true. I think it's a good tip to clean up the ZIP file once you are done with it.  Well said.